# Method (everything) of object Global failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro which takes the body of an email, splits it into an array and places it into excel. It then uses colons to split rows into [label] and [data].

For some reason it has stopped working. I had some good help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188299/problems-defining-excel-range-to-paste-array-into-from-outlook) but it has now failed in the second subroutine and I can't get my head around the error. I am sure it's something simple, possibly related to running from outlook or incorrect definition of ranges. Everything using rows, cells, range object etc gives this error.

The exact error is `Runtime 1004 error. Method [cells, rows] of object Global failed`

I have used a comment to mark the point where problems begin:

```
Private oXLApp As Object, oXLWb As Object, oXLWs As Object
Sub Thermo_to_excel()
    Dim myOlApp As Object, mynamespace As Object
    Dim ThermoMail As Object
    Dim msgText, delimtedMessage, Delim1 As String



    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
    Set ThermoMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    delimtedMessage = ThermoMail.Body

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set oXLWs = oXLWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Truncated [Array definition goes here]

    With oXLWs
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value = _
        oXLApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(messageArray)
    End With

    Call splitAtColons
    ThermoMail.Close (olDiscard)
End Sub

Sub splitAtColons()

Dim Roows As Integer
'PROBLEMS start here now
Roows = Cells(oXLWs.Rows.Count & "," & oXLWs.ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row 

Range("A1").Select
Range("A1:B" & Roows).Font.Name = Range("B1").Font.Name
Range("A1:B" & Roows).NumberFormat = "@"



'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do Until Z = Roows

If Not InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ":") = 0 Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Trim(Mid(ActiveCell.Value, InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ":") + 1))
    ActiveCell.Value = Left(ActiveCell.Value, InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ":"))
Else
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Trim(ActiveCell.Value)
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
End If
If ActiveCell.Value = "" And Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "" Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Roows = Roows - 1
Z = Z - 1
End If


    Range("A" & Z + 2).Select
    Z = Z + 1
Loop
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: fails? can you elaborate what exactly fails?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Please see my edit.

Comment: you still can ;) which line throws the error?

Comment: Roows = Cells(oXLWs.Rows.Count & "," & oXLWs.ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Look what that evaluates to...and compare to what you would like it to evaluate to.

Comment: I guess that ActiveCell property is not defined by Worksheet, so the code ```oXLWs.ActiveCell``` causes error. ActiveCell is defined for Application or Window but not on Worksheet. Am I right?

Comment: Try something like this: ```oXLWs.Cells(oXLWs.Rows.Count, oXLWs.Application.ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row```

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Not really. It works intermittently. I believe it is a result of running operations in excel from outlook VBA as it works in excel vba editor every time.

Comment: @Cassiopeia Does the answer below help you, or are you still running into this problem?

Comment: Sorry I have had really limited time to develop this recently. I think I may have tried something like the answer below before but I will give this a go when I have a chance. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: To make matters worse, I am unable to consistently reproduce the problem - it often works fine.

Comment: @Cassiopeia That's the problem with using `Range`, `Cells`, & `Columns` without a worksheet or workbook reference. They will work just fine as long as the `ActiveSheet` is the one you want to reference; otherwise they will not work.

Comment: @Cassiopeia Are you still having troubles with this?

Comment: Yes, it will not run if excel is open. I have worked around it by making sure excel is not running before calling the script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are not fully defining your `Range`, `Cells`, & `Columns` functions. Try adding `oXLWs.` before each of those functions, or add a `With oXLWs` line and add `.` before each of those functions and see what happens.

If you run this in Excel, the `Range`, `Cells`, & `Columns` functions will work because they will refer to the active worksheet. If you run this through Outlook, it may not work if the sheet is not active.